# Safari mix-blend-mode with Swiper not working

Tags: html, css

I am using Swiper in my project. Each slide has an image inside. When the slide changes, the color of the absolute positioned parent block changes. Mix-blend-mode allows the image to change color.

Html structure

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/250" alt="" class="swiper-slide__img">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/250" alt="" class="swiper-slide__img">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/250" alt="" class="swiper-slide__img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.block {
  width: 400px;
}
.swiper {
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ivstepin/pen/MWoXjpE

It's okay working in Chrome, but not working in Safari. I see Safari supported this css style, what's wrong?